# Mass update ASCII bullets in imported product descriptions to HTML/CSS list items

Tags: product, import, product-view

I've imported a large catalog of products that contain ASCII bullets. I need to convert them to style friendly HTML/CSS ordered lists and list items. Here is an example of how the specific segment of product descriptions are currently stored:

```
Features include:
•        USB interface
•        USB cable included
•        Power supply included
•        All-in-one-box convenience
•        Energy Star qualified
•        Average lifespan 360,000 hours / 60 million lines
•        Autocutter life of 1.5 million cuts
```

I've considered using jQuery to "style" those bullet instances to allow an opening `<ul>` tag then iterate through the `<li>` tags. I think ultimately updating with a "find and replace" MySQL query (e.g. http://www.magetricks.com/tricks/find-and-replace-a-string-with-mysql-query-or-how-to-automate-base-url-change). I might just have to get granular and replace

```
Features include:
```

with

```
Features include:<ul>
```

Anyone faced a similar issue? Is there a better way to address "normalizing" data like this after import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea should be: Do it before import, then you have much less problems.

I would find a markdown parser, check that the parser parses it correctly, fix the stuff with regex to make it parseable and then run a script one time to fix everything in the database.

After this you need to fix your import, so you don't import broken descriptions.